# Using HERE in Forth for temporary space

Tags: memory, forth

I'm writing a game in Forth (for learning purposes).

The game is played on a "10 cell board". I'm trying new stuff so I did

```
here 10 [char] - fill
```

to set up the space for the board.
Then, to play 'X' in position 3

```
[char] X here 3 + c!
```

This has been working fine, but raises the question

Is this OK?
What if the board was a million cells wide?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The described approach has the certain environmental dependencies, so your program just have to match the environmental restriction on programs of your Forth system (i.e. that you use).

#### 1. Size of the data space

The word [`UNUSED`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/UNUSED) returns "the amount of space remaining in the region addressed by `HERE`". So, a program can check the available space.

Also, according to the subsection [4.1.3 Other system documentation](https://forth-standard.org/standard/doc#subsection.4.1.3) of the Forth Standard:

> A system shall provide the following information:
> [...]
> program **data space available**, in address units;

So, you have just to check whether your Forth system provides enough data space for you program, and how the available data space can be configured (if any).

#### 2. Transient regions

In the general case, it is not safe for a portable program to use the data space without reserving it.

According to the section [3.3.3.6 Other transient regions](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:transient) of the Forth Standard, the contents of the data space regions identified by `PAD`, `WORD`, and `#>` may become invalid after the data space is allocated. Сonsequently, the contents of the region identified by `HERE` may become invalid after the contents of the regions identified by `PAD`, `WORD`, and `#>` are changed.

See also [A.3.3.3.6 Other transient regions](https://forth-standard.org/standard/rationale#paragraph.A.3.3.3.6):

> In many existing Forth systems, these areas are at `HERE` or just beyond it, hence the many restrictions.

Moreover, some Forth systems may use the region identified by `HERE` in internal purposes during translation. E.g. Gforth 0.7.9 uses this region when decoding escaped strings.
The phrase:

```
s\" test\-passed" cr here over type cr type cr
```

outputs:

```
test-passed
test-passed
```

So, you have to check the restrictions of your Forth system whether you may use the region identified by `HERE` without reserving the space (and in what conditions).